# Self-referencing Entity may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following entity:

```
public class Department
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public int? HeadDepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department HeadDepartment { get; set; }

        public List<Department> ChildDepartments { get; set; }
    }
```

I Add-Migration and then try to update database and as a result:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Departments_Departments_HeadDepartmentId' on table 'Departments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

I try next:

```
builder.Entity<Department>()
                .HasOne(p => p.HeadDepartment)
                .WithMany(p => p.ChildDepartments)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.HeadDepartmentId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

But it doesnt help.

Comment: I see you changed OnDelete but did you try to change both OnDelete and OnUpdate?

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you did I assume it's the first (or previous) migration that keeps throwing the error.

Comment: .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict) => help me